# mock a function which is used in another function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I am writing test for my async action in react redux, for sake of addressing just the issue I simplified the code here. Here is my action function:

```
export function updateUserAuthenticationStatus(){
return function(dispatch){
   return axios.get(getLoginStatusUrl())
        .then(response => {
               const middlewares = [thunk];
               const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
               const store = mockStore();
    return store.dispatch(updateUserAuthenticationStatus()).then(()=>{
       //expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.eql(expectedActions);
    });
            });
        }).catch(function(response){
    });
  }
}
```

So the problem is the function getLoginStatusUrl() which does couple of checks in the cookie and return the appropriate url based on some conditions. So what I want is to mock this function to return for example test.com then I can test my action as follows:

```
it("", () => {
        **here I want to mock getLoginStatusUrl() to return test.com**
    nock("test.com")
        .get("/")
        .reply(200,"test detail");

})
```

How can I mock the getLoginStatusUrl() to return test.com in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need it to return test.com specifically. Use a library such as [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter). I haven't used it personaly but I'v used fetch-mock to mock fetch api requests so that concept should be exactly the same.

Lets say `getLoginStatusUrl()` returns `/loginStatus`, (because you haven't shown what it does return).

Example:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

// Mock any GET request to /users
// arguments for reply are (status, data, headers)
mock.onGet('/loginStatus').reply(200, {
  loginSuccess: true
});

axios.get('/loginStatus')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

The example code is untested but hopefuly you get the idea. Just read the library README.md.

In scenario's where you want to stub/mock out private imports that aren't used in axios requests like this you can use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) or [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) if you are using es6 syntax such as imports.

@HamedMinaee If you do not know the path at all, you can just do something like `onGet('/')`, it's all in the README.md. after the test I imagine their is a way to reset this so that not all tests using axios are affected by it.

```
afterEach(() => {
    // reset the axios mock here so that '/' doesn't affect all requests or something.
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering I will start looking into it and let you know about the result. Just a question: I have a function getLoginStatusUrl for getting the url and we do not know about the path at all but here in mock function we have onGet('/loginStatus') which we define the path '/loginStatus' how does it address this issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot I am working on it and let you know about the result

Comment: When I check the read me file for this: If you do not know the path at all, you can just do something like onGet('/') I cannot find anything. Am I missing sth?

Comment: @HamedMinaee Or specify no path such as `onGet()`. That's in readme

Answer (score 2):

Try this out with sinon.

```
import {getLoginStatusUrl} from './some/path.js'

let stub = sinon.stub(),
opts = { call: getLoginStatusUrl() };

stub.withExactArgs().returns("somePredefinedReturnValue")
```

Comment: Thanks does this work if getLoginStatusUrl is a private function?

Comment: export the function as an ES module like `export function getLoginStatusUrl() {...}`, then import it here. I assume that you do the same inside your action.

Comment: Yeah but for sake of best practice in writing code is it a good idea to export a fuction because of test purpose?

Comment: Normally we don't change the code just for testing. Are you calling a local function inside the action? If so you can export it as an ES module and import it in your test file. just add `export` at the beginning of the function definition. By the way if the function is local, then you can't even unit test it.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Instead of exporting it just use rewire which I linked in my answer if you are going to do this.

Comment: The best option is to pass it as props to the component. Then in your test you can pass props too like this. `_props = {
      prop1: 'value1',
      getLoginStatusUrl : (_spies.getLoginStatusUrl = sinon.spy()),

    }
    _wrapper = shallow(<Component {..._props} />)`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Can you please the the updated part: this is what I have in my test :  return store.dispatch(updateUserAuthenticationStatus()).then(()=>{
       //expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.eql(expectedActions);
    }); so if I use stub does it work on this part?

Comment: question is not clear now. Why are you using mocks inside your actions? Please update the question so that I can understand your action and it's flow first. Did you try the suggested approach?